# C# - Json converter

Tags: c#, json

Example I have following code (C# - Console App)

```
static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
{
    Account account = new Account { Name = "Test", Code = (AccountCode)"Code" };
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account));
}

public class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public AccountCode Code { get; set; }
}

public struct AccountCode
{
    public AccountCode(string value)
        : this()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("AccountCode cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        Value = value.ToUpperInvariant();
    }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator AccountCode(string value)
    {
        return new AccountCode(value);
    }

    public static explicit operator AccountCode? (string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return new AccountCode(value);
        }
    }

    public static explicit operator string(AccountCode code)
    {
        return code.Value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is AccountCode && this == (AccountCode)obj;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(AccountCode x, AccountCode y)
    {
        return string.Equals(x.Value, y.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(AccountCode x, AccountCode y)
    {
        return !string.Equals(x.Value, y.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
```

The output is:
`{"Name": "Test", "Code": { "Value": "CODE" }`

My expectation is:
`{"Name": "Test", "Code": "CODE" }`

Note: AccountCode is a struct but I would like to serialize/deserialize as a normal string. How should I do?

Comment: Please don't place tags in your question title, and please ensure that it's descriptive of your problem.

Comment: You can implement custom [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm)

Comment: What's the point of using this struct anyway? It doesn't seem to have any benefit over simply using a string...

Answer (score 0):

Code in Account class is an object of AccountCode that's why while serializing it, JsonConverter is putting it into curly braces. You have to either change the Code property into string or manipulate the serialized json